# obtain position of nth-child to variable

Tags: jquery, variables, jquery-selectors

I have a table:

---

```
<table width="160" align="center" id="my_table">
    <tbody>
       <tr>
          <td><img src="Color1.png" width="160" height="40" alt="1"></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
          <td><img src="Color2.png" width="160" height="40" alt="2"></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
          <td><img src="Color3.png" width="160" height="40" alt="3"></td>
       </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

---

I allow the user to move the blocks of colors up and down - there are more colors. At the end  of the process I wish to know which position (which child position) each of the alt's are in and save that to separate variables using jQuery. I've tried:

```
$('#my_table').on('click', 'img', function() {
    var color_rated_1 = $("#my_table.tr:nth-child(1)");
    alert("color_rated_1 is " + color_rated_1);
});
$('#my_table').on('click', 'img', function() {
    var color_rated_2 = $(".tr:nth-child(2)");
    alert("color_rated_2 is " + color_rated_2);
});
$('#my_table').on('click', 'img', function() {
    var color_rated_3 = $("#my_table tr:nth-child(3)");
    alert("color_rated_3 is " + color_rated_3);
});
```

Note that each of these are a little different - and I've tried numerous other variations over the past many days. I have also looked at all of the examples I have find and nothing seems to work. Help. And thanks. Rick

Comment: Please elaborate on your explanation of what you want to achieve, because your code makes no sense at all.

Answer (score 2):

The index is provided when you iterate over the collection:

```
$("#my_table img").each(function(index, image){
    alert(image.alt + " is at position " + index);
});​
```

You can also use [`.index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/) to get a location within a collection:

```
var $table = $("#my_table");
$table.on("click", "img", function(){
    alert($table.find("img").index(this)); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
var $table = $('#my_table').on('click', 'img', function() {
   var index = $table.find("img").index(this);

   alert( $(this).attr("src") + " is " + index);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YAAaE/

When the image is clicked it will find all images in the table and evaluate the clicked image's index using the [`.index()` method](http://api.jquery.com/index/).

Answer (score 0):

In order to get an array of a the `alt` values in order that they appear you can do the following:

```
   var order = $.makeArray($("#my_table img").map(function() {
       return $(this).attr("alt");
   }));

   alert("The order is " + order.join(", "));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BUmr2/1/

Or you can order create an object keyed by the the alt:

```
   var indexes = {};

   $("#my_table img").each(function(i) {
       indexes[$(this).attr("alt")] = i;
   });

   alert("Index 1 is " + indexes["1"]);
   alert("Index 2 is " + indexes["2"]);
   alert("Index 3 is " + indexes["3"]);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ec9HY/

Comment: Alternatively, you could use `.map` as well: `$("#my_table img").map(function(){return this.alt;}).get().join(", ")`.